# How to describe the stage between "success" and "warning" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am programming a web-app and using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options). I am using style classes for different buttons

As you can see, there are style classes like: danger, success, warning.

[image]

So, I am missing a state between success and warning - like the yellow traffic light.

Is there an English word for this state?

Comment: How about *note*?

Comment: I thought something like an adjevtive, something which lean to the others.

Comment: What is wrong with *info*? There is no yellow.

Comment: Between "warning" and "danger" would be *alert*.

Comment: I know that there is now yellow. Well, it should be like 'normal' behaviour. green = complete, yellow = one to  go, orange = two to go, red = three to got. I fixed the link. Also it is between success and warning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I don't think the picture is representative of the asker's original question?

Comment: "Info" is commonly used in computer contexts.

Comment: @jxh I took a screenshot of that image from the website.

Comment: If the picture is representative of your question, you can use *info*. Just change the color to yellow instead of blue. If it is not, can you put in a different picture?

Comment: I think the description "like a yellow traffic light" is misleading 1) the colour is really "amber" (*I know, I'm being a pedant!*)  2) the order is green, amber, red. But here you have six different colours. 3) "warning" is one way of interpreting the amber traffic light i.e "Warning: the lights are about to change to red". But that's me. Maybe others don't have that problem.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, in german it is plain old 'yellow', sorry. I need a state between green and 'amber'. :) Well, maybe I will go with info and get rid of the yellow colour and using this blue one instead.

Comment: Leave the question though, it's intriguing. Why does "success" follow "primary"? Why does "info" precede "warning"? Maybe you're looking for *"help"*? If you could explain the meaning behind each word, I think it would help us old crusties. :))

Comment: I really do now know. I guess there is special order.

Comment: @jxh proposed "note", **notice** is an alternative. "read me" may be envisaged, but it is generally used in the context of a program installation.

Comment: The context for this question is very specialized and not really suitable for this forum. Bootstrap button styles are there for a purpose, which is not to describe or map to  the gradations of meaning between Success and Warning. But within this context, one normally uses Info as the neutral choice. It says "here's some info, neither good nor bad, just info you may need or be interested in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps ***[Caution](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/caution)*** or ***[Attention](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attention)*** will serve?

> **Caution**
>   Care taken to avoid danger or mistakes:
>   *anyone receiving a suspect package should exercise extreme caution*
>
> **Attention**
>   Notice taken of someone or something; the regarding of someone or something as interesting or important:
>   *he drew attention to three spelling mistakes*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/caution
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attention

Comment: Caution, Attention, Warning, these are all synonyms.

Comment: On some airplanes they have a Caution/Advisory panel which display things that are not as severe as Warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that *alert* could fit the bill, or perhaps also *alarm*.

If you want a noun that doesn't describe the notification itself but rather the underlying state/condition, you could consider something like *hazard* or *risk*.

Comment: I would class *Alarm* at a level quite equivalent to *Danger* and *Alert* just beween *Warning* and *Danger*.

Comment: The title has been changed. My mistake, but it was rectified within minutes.

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't read the original Q thoroughly. In that case I like *attention* (suggested in answer below).

Answer (score 0):

**Proceed with care**

OR

**Proceed with caution**